# GITHUB Action Connect to Redshift Database Server

Tags: github, github-actions, circleci

Currently we use circleci for build and deployment and we are moving from circleci to github actions and I'm struck on one specific step.

1. In circleci we connect to our production redshift database and execute bunch of SQL Queries. How I do the same using github action.
2. Currently in circleci, we use middleman node

   - &connect_to_middleman_aws_node
     run:
     name: Connects to middleman node to forward conection to redshift
     command: | # Remember to use virtual-env
     source /tmp/python_venv/bin/activate
     ssh -nNT -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -L $REDSHIFT_PORT:$REDSHIFT_HOST:$REDSHIFT_PORT ubuntu@airflow.xxxxxxx.com
     background: true
   - add_ssh_keys:
     fingerprints:
     - "0a:6e:61:b9:19:43:93:5c:8c:4c:7c:fc:6e:aa:74:89"

What is the equivalent in Github action. If anyone has done this, can you please me the sample code.